# Is it true that $(PQ+I)^{-1}P = P(QP+I)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $P$ is an $N \times M$-matrix while $Q$ is an $M \times N$-matrix, how can it be shown that $(PQ+I_N)^{-1}P = P(QP+I_M)^{-1}$, where $I_N$ and $I_M$ are identity matrices? We assume that both inverses exist.

Edit:
I am curious about this from reading about an alternate form of ridge regression estimate where $\beta = (X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty = X^T(XX^T+\lambda I)^{-1}y$. I wonder in general if there is such a property.

What I got so far is that since $P=P$, we have $(PQ+I)(PQ+I)^{-1}P = P(QP+I)^{-1}(QP+I)$. Then I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my question.

Comment: Very nice identity. If M is much smaller than N it casa save computational power :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(PQ + I)^{-1}P \\= (PQ + I)^{-1}P(QP + I)(QP + I)^{-1} \\= (PQ + I)^{-1}(PQP + P)(QP + I)^{-1}\\=(PQ + I)^{-1}(PQ + I)P(QP + I)^{-1} \\= P(QP + I)^{-1}$$

Comment: That's great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply from left and right with suitable matrices which eliminates the inverses...

Comment: Thanks Johan for your hint. I edited my question.